# Web API deserialising ajax posted null values as "null" string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

We're invoking a web-api controller as follows:-

```
var foo = ...; // may be null.
...

var data = { Foo: foo, ... };
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    type: 'POST'
    data: data,
    });
```

When the data is deserialised on the server into our model:-

```
public class BarController : ApiController
{
  public void Post(Bar bar)
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class Bar
{
  public string Foo { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

The value `"null"` is bound to `Foo` instead of `null`.

It's important for business reasons that we use use the `www-form-urlencoded` content type rather than JSON.

It does not appear to be feasible to replace the built-in `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` as it relies on a number of internal classes (in particular, it instantiates a `FormUrlEncodedParser`, and there appear to be no hooks to extend its behaviour).

The problem appears to be that [`FormUrlEncodedParser`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1b78397f32fc#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/Parsers/FormUrlEncodedParser.cs) is interpreting the input as `"null"` rather than `null`.

Is there a way to have web api to bind `null` rather than `"null"` to Foo?

Alternately, is there a way to have jquery omit the key for any `null` value from the `data` passed to `$.ajax`?

Comment: Which model does your controller action take as parameter and how does it look like the signature?

Comment: Why not just leave out properties you wish to be `null`?

Comment: The object is being generated elsewhere and the property isn't always null.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, we're looping through the object and deleting any key whose value is `null` before we call `$.ajax`:-

```
var data = ...;

for (i in data ) {
    if (!data [i]) {
        delete data [i];
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: ...
    type: 'POST'
    data: data,
    });
```

I'm still hoping there's a tidier place to handle this, though.